# Is the practice of down-casting to set derived class member variables recommended?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Let us take an example:

```
class Parent{
}

class Derived1:public Parent{
public:
       int x;
}

class Derived2:public Parent{
public:
       int y;
}

main()
{
  int i;
  std::cin >> i;
  Parent *p;
  switch(i)
  {
  case 0:
          p = new Derived1()
          static_cast<Derived1>(p)-> x = 1;
          break;
  case 1:
          p = new Derived2()
          static_cast<Derived2>(p)-> y = 2;
          break;
  }
  process(*p);
}
```

Is the practice of down-casting to set derived class member variables recommended? And is there a cleaner alternative to the above ?

Comment: Why not pass the initial value of the member to the constructor?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `process(p)`, not `process(*p)` ?

Comment: @Brian, well I can of course, its just in my actual code, I determine the values of the Derived class sequentially I don't want to keep temporary variables arround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your casts are wrong, you need to cast to a pointer (`p` is a pointer) :

```
static_cast<Derived1*>(p)
                    ^
```

And you don't need those casts, just assign derived pointers to base ones :

```
  Parent *p;
  switch(i)
  {
      case 0:
      {
              Derived1* d1 = new Derived1();
              d1->x = 1;
              p = d1;
              break;
      }
      case 1:
      {
              Derived2* d2 = new Derived2();
              d2-> y = 2;
              p = d2;
              break;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code is broken.
If you cast parent to derived you should cast pointers or references.

```
static_cast<Derived1*>(p)
```

Instead of creating object, and then setting fields you could pass it as a parameter to constructor for example.

```
p = new Derived1(x)
```

Actually, as soon as you know what type will object have you can cast pointer to parent safely. But I haven't seen any recommendation to do this.